# Connect my android application to facebook so the user can login through it (JAVA)

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-graph-api, twitter, gmail

I am creating an android mobile application which is for the tourism. My question is:
How can I make the user to login through Facebook, Twitter, or Gmail instead of creating a new account?

I already found the facebook doc. for that but not sure if it will work or not https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/#import

I am using Eclipse and the programming language is Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't the documentation work?

Comment: Hey EWit, a friend of mine told me that it didn't worked with him so I wanted to make sure if anyone else tried it or not as I still didn't reach this step I am just analyzing what I need to add (Functional Requirements) 
did you tried it?

Comment: I did a year or so ago and it worked back then. No idea what they've changed since then. But most likely for a company like Facebook they tend to make sure their API's are functional and well documented because it does equal money for them.

Comment: I see then maybe my friend did something wrong in one of the steps..
Thanks a lot :D

Comment: How abt Twitter API do you know anything about it?